# How to run multiple services on one sub domain with google cloud

Tags: node.js, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are currently starting our next api version and will be rolling this out in stages.

Currently we have api.domain.com/v3
The domain api.domain.com is pointing to a compute engine.

We need to roll out a specific part of our v4 api api.domain.com/v4 which is currently running on an app engine.

Is there a service or something in GCP that can route different urls to different services?

Essentially we want everything going to the compute engine, and then anything /v4 going to the app engine.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider Google Cloud HTTP(s) Load Balancers with forwarding rules and Network Endpoint Groups to manage traffic.  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/better-load-balancing-for-app-engine-cloud-run-and-functions

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley, that looks like what we need.  I will have a play and if all good, i shall let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What John mentioned has worked a treat, using load balancers